# Generic type conversion for objects with traits in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a trait `Mode`, several structs `MyModeN` and an object-like struct `<MyMode: Mode> Obj<MyMode>`.

I want to build a general conversion function that outputs the new object, with some reinitialization. Writing the function is not the issue, getting the type-signature and the impl block correctly is.

I tried

```
impl <MyMode: Mode, NewMode: Mode> Obj<MyMode> {
    pub fn convert(self, m: NewMode) -> Obj<NewMode> { unimplemented!() }
}
```

but this fails because `NewMode` is not specified in the object itself. Using `impl` instead of NewMode, i.e.

```
pub fn convert(self, m: impl Mode) -> Obj<impl Mode>
```

also does not help since then I cannot use

```
impl Obj<MyModeN> { .. }
```

blocks.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: Try adding the 2nd generic parameter to the function instead of the impl block: `pub fn convert<NewMode: Mode>(self, m: NewMode)...`

Comment: Two questions - why can you not define a trait implementation like `trait Convert<D:Mode> { fn convert(self) -> D; }` and then implement stepper conversion implementations? And secondly, what is the point of your `Obj<_>` "object-like struct"? Could you not get away with an `impl Deref` and `impl DerefMut` on `Obj<T>`?

Comment: re: `Obj<_>` - are you coming from a purely functional language (i.e. Haskell/Scala or equivalent)? I think you may be trying to emulate a pattern from those languages in a way that will hurt you more than it benefits you in the long run

Comment: What is an "object-like struct"? Is there such a thing as a struct that is not object-like? Is this terminology used in some other language community that I am not aware of?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld yes, I used to program Haskell a lot and most of the time Rust works quite similar; as I said I am new to Rust and if the answer is 'do something completely different' then that is totally fine.

Comment: @trentcl What I was refered to is to use the struct similar as one would use classes in OOP, i.e. some data + some methods. Sorry if my lingo is off I am not a professional programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the 2nd generic parameter to the function instead of the impl block:

```rust
pub fn convert<NewMode: Mode>(self, m: NewMode)...
```